# How can I invert the colors for only a given application on Android? (and not for all applications)

Tags: color

How can I invert the colors for only a given application on Android? (and not for all applications)

Turning on the "color inversion" option in the settings invert the colors for all applications.

Comment: If the app does not use "secure screens" (secure screens e.g. are empty on a screenshot) it should be possible to use an app that creates a permanent overlay such as NightShift but instead of just making the display red it could invert the colors. I have read that some night shift apps already include an invert mode, but I don't know which one allows to configure it in a way so that only some apps are affected.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible on stock Android. [Google help](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151800?hl=en) clearly says :

> Color inversion applies to everything on your device, including media.

If you are on Android 10 using Dark theme and Color inversion together as explained (see link) may be an option in some cases.

If you root your phone and install custom ROM that supports [per app color inversion](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1797698), you are lucky. AFAIK, there isn't an app or Xposed module available for this purpose

Comment: Additionally in Developer Options there is a "Force Dark Mode" or "Override force-dark" which will make all apps render in dark mode, regardless if the app is correctly configured (YMMV).